# Remover o Group_Concat e listar cada um separadamente

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Quero remover o group_concat para listar cada um separadamente, alguma dica?

```
SELECT
   U.login, 
   (SELECT Group_concat(AC.curso ORDER BY id ASC) 
    FROM   alunos_cursos AC 
           LEFT JOIN cursos C 
                  ON AC.curso = C.id 
    WHERE  AC.aluno = U.id 
           AND AC.disponivel = 1 


     AND AC.curso <> 9) CURSOS 
FROM   usuarios U 
Where NIVEL_ACESSO=0
```

Exemplo:

De

```
 LOGIN   CURSOS
    1     100, 112, 12, 43, 3
    2     9, 25, 6, 78, 44, 70
```

Para

```
  LOGIN   CURSOS
    1     100
    1     112
    1     12
    1     43
    1     3
    2     9
    2     25
    [...]
```

Comment: Olá @Hiago. Coloque a sua questão em português pf. Está no **SOpt**.

Comment: Obrigado @JoãoMartins não percebi, sou novo na plataforma.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT U.login,
      AC.course
  FROM users U
  INNER JOIN students_courses AC ON AC.student = U.id
  LEFT JOIN courses C ON AC.course= C.id
WHERE level_access = 0
  AND AC.avaliable = 1
  AND AC.course <> 9
ORDER BY U.login
```

Comment: Muito bem pensado, porém não está retornando de forma correta. O ID do aluno está vindo incorreto, como se estivesse juntando com outro número. =/ Estou tentando ver onde pode estar o erro.

Comment: @HiagoMendes coloca a descrição das estruturas das tabelas então para podermos avaliar qual seria a melhor solução. Se for possível com alguns dados de exemplo

Comment: Creio que colocando o código em Português dará para entender melhor. Não coloquei em português porquê não percebi que era SOpt. Irei editar o Post e atualizar as informações. 
No caso, estou relacionando duas tabelas onde pego o Cadastro do aluno e procuro o curso dele pelo ID em outra tabela.

Comment: @HiagoMendes na realidade não vejo como a informação de que o `id` está "juntando com outro número" poderia proceder, afinal a coluna está explícita na `query`

Comment: Irei tentar averiguar como reverter este problema usando sua query como base. Já estou há 8 horas tentando.

Comment: @HiagoMendes coloca a estrutura e os dados de exemplo da sua tabela que eu faço um fiddle pra resolver o seu problema

Comment: Não sei se é permitido, mas não custa perguntar. Você teria a possibilidade de fazer um acesso remoto para dar uma olhada? Não costumo utilizar phpmyadmin e nem a mexer com banco de dados, na verdade estou criando uma forma de utilizar os dados dos alunos em outra plataforma.